# android home screen widget, can anyone tell me what can i use in a homescreen widget, can i use autocompletetextview?

Tags: android, android-widget

Can anyone tell me if i can use autocompletetextview in my homescreen widget or if not what can i use in homescreen widget, or how can i conect it to the my autocomplete, because i want some sort of input widget. if anyone can reference me or paste some code that had the same issue before it would be great, because i have red that it might not be possible to put input mechanism as home screen widgets! :D thanks.

here is my xml

```
    android:id="@+id/autoDeni"

     android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:maxLines="1"

    android:hint="Име...."


    />
```

```
   <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
       android:layout_width="35dp"
       android:layout_height="35dp" />
```

Comment: See [App widgets - Creating the app widget layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not possible to use editText or autocomplete in widget, only as button pic or as a list, 
here is some code for the widget

```
Override
public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent)
{
    if(intent.getAction()==null)
    {
        ctxt.startService(new Intent(ctxt,ToggleService.class));
    }
    else
    {
        super.onReceive(ctxt, intent);
    }

}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context,AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int [] appWidgetIds)
{
    context.startService(new Intent(context,ToggleService.class));
    //RemoteViews buildUpdate(context);
}

public static class ToggleService extends IntentService
    {
    public ToggleService() {
        super("AppWidget$ToggleService");

        }



@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    ComponentName me = new ComponentName(this,AppWidget.class);
    AppWidgetManager mgr= AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
    mgr.updateAppWidget(me,buildUpdate(this));
}

private RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context context)
{
    RemoteViews updateViews=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget);
    AudioManager audioManager=(AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Activity.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if(audioManager.getRingerMode()==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT)
    {
        updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.phoneState,R.drawable.silent);
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

    }
    else {
        updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.phoneState,R.drawable.phone123);
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

    }
    Intent i=new Intent(this, AppWidget.class);
    PendingIntent pi= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, i,0);
    updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.phoneState,pi);
    return updateViews;
}

  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use any type of 'EditText' in a widget. if you have to do this, simply open a dialog when clicking a widget and do your work there.

note that only these widgets are allowed to be used in midgets:

- AnalogClock
- Button
- Chronometer
- ImageButton
- ImageView
- ProgressBar
- TextView

Comment: this can help:
http://www.androidbook.com/akc/display?url=DisplayNoteIMPURL&reportId=3300&downerUserId=satya

Comment: @Keyhan Asghari: Dialog  also not possible open from home screen widget.so only one way ,launch an activity on widget click

Comment: you mean like call my MainActivity(beacause i have only one screen(class) )

Comment: not MainActivity if it's your widget configuration activity, any new Activity with transparent background and small height,width.